# how to get array of values as a values in json object in android

Tags: android, json, xml

```
String finalData = "{"Books":[{"name":"Genesis","chapters1":["Chapter No:1","Chapter No:2","Chapter No:3","Chapter No:4","Chapter No:5","Chapter No:6","Chapter No:7","Chapter No:8","Chapter No:9","Chapter No:10"]}]};



private void ChaptersData(String finalData) {

        try {
            JSONObject mainchapter=new JSONObject(finalData);
            JSONArray chapterdata=mainchapter.getJSONArray("Books");
            chapterList=new String[chapterdata.length()];
             for (int j=0;j<=chapterdata.length();j++){
                 JSONObject chapInterData=(JSONObject) chapterdata.get(j);

                 String chapter=chapInterData.getString(0);

                 Log.e("Chapter", " "+chapter);
                 chapterList[j]=chapter;
             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

now how can i get the chapters from json object

Answer (score 0):

put this code inside your for loop

```
JSONArray chap = chapInterData.getJSONArray("chapters1");
for(int k =0;k<chap.length();k++)
{
    String data=chap.getString(k);
    Log.e("data", " "+data);
}
```

insert `data` in your desired `array`

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code using **[Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)** library which is more reliable and easy to use for json parsing:

```
String finalData = "{\"Books\":[{\"name\":\"Genesis\",\"chapters\":[\"Chapter No:1\",\"Chapter No:2\",\"Chapter No:3\",\"Chapter No:4\",\"Chapter No:5\",\"Chapter No:6\",\"Chapter No:7\",\"Chapter No:8\",\"Chapter No:9\",\"Chapter No:10\"]}]}";

private void ChaptersData(String finalData) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    BookModel bookModel = gson.fromJson(finalData, BookModel.class);
    BookModel.Books[] books = bookModel.getBooks();

    for (BookModel.Books book : books) {
        String[] chapters = book.getChapters();
        for (String chapter : chapters) {
            Log.e("Chapter", " " + chapter);
        }
    }
}

class BookModel {
    private Books[] Books;

    public Books[] getBooks() {
        return Books;
    }

    class Books {
        private String name;

        private String[] chapters;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String[] getChapters() {
            return chapters;
        }

        public void setChapters(String[] chapters1) {
            this.chapters = chapters1;
        }
    }
}
```

add this to your app **build.gradle** dependency tag:

> compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'